# Excel 2007 shortcut?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel-2007, formatting, copy-paste

Is there a shortcut in Excel 2007 (or a simple way to define one) to paste all copied values, but without formatting ?

I'm entering some data in tables, and it would really save my life, that one.

Comment: Alt+E, S, V pastes just values. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Randolph . thanks. That will do for now. (Still not comfortable with this new Excel ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is Alt+H, V, V

Answer (score 1):

Add the "Paste Values" button to your Quick Access toolbar.

1. Right-click any tab on the menu bar, and then go to "Customize Quick Access Toolbar."
2. Pick "Customize" from the Categories on the left. Under "Choose Commands from," pick "Home Tab."
3. Pick "Paste Values" from the long list. Click the "Add" button, then click "Ok."

Answer (score 0):

Since you're going from Excel to Excel, a trick is to run two copies of Excel.  Start the first one normally, but then run Excel again, and then open the second file.  Copy and paste then goes between the two Excels as if it was text.

Comment: No, I'm not copying from one sheet to another. I'm entering some gigantic tables, which have a lot of same values, so while entering the data, I copy it so I don't have to type it. That's what I ment under "excel to excel" ... although, yes, I could've made it more clear.